# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [ExpressionEngine® Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Resetting entry_id count](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/resetting-entry-id-count)

  **Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it possible to have category name instead of template_group in uri?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14888/is-it-possible-to-have-category-name-instead-of-template-group-in-uri)

  **Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Stash set_list not displaying channel entry loop](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/stash-set-list-not-displaying-channel-entry-loop)

  **Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Errors when importing a MySQL database](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15113/errors-when-importing-a-mysql-database)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Channel > Entry > Relationship > Grid > Field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/channel-entry-relationship-grid-field)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Invalid EE Conditional Variable](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15358/invalid-ee-conditional-variable)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Migrations for ExpressionEngine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/migrations-for-expressionengine)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Channels with Grids not retaining data](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/channels-with-grids-not-retaining-data)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Primary Category display in EE2.6 Relationships loop](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15513/primary-category-display-in-ee2-6-relationships-loop)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Exp:resso Store + UPS Shipping](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/expresso-store-ups-shipping)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Comment: Seems good. Glad to see more people participate this time around.